# Can we Connect redis cluster with master nodes only via spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster

We created redid cluster with redis 5. In our cluster we have 3 master and 6 slave nodes which is recommended by Redis.

Now to connect redid cluster via spring boot, we used

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[0]=192.168.2.4:7379
.
.
```

This way we configured all redis nodes in spring boot configuration including 3 masters and 6 slave. Want to understand, is it required to pass all redis node configuration to spring boot? Can we just go ahead with master node configurations in spring boot? If possible, please share reason behind the suggestion.

Comment: Would using [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) help you achieve what you want?

Comment: Sentinel is something different. I want to go with multi-master cluster for which Sentinel is not required.

Comment: how did you solve this problem?